# Images are not showing in Crystal Resports 8 in VB6 applications

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

VB6 application that uses Crystal Reports 8, but images in the reports are not showing.

Images do show fine in our dev environment but in the terminal server win2012 that users access to get to the application, when running a report the images simply do not show.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I changed the images on the Oracle database <LONG RAW> type field for bmp instead of jpg and now they show, but they used to work fine with jpg before. Any idea why would jpg stop working? I don't want to keep them in bmp because the file size is a lot bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the 'real' paths of images in your application when running OUT the IDE.

To test, add a MsgBox that show the paths of images, so you can discover is it's wrong. If paths are corrects, then maybe a users permission problem.

Comment: Hello Giorgio, thanks a lot for your reply. The images are stored in a <LONG RAW> column in an Oracle DB, I have a screen on the VB6 app that shows the same image directly on screen and it works, so I believe the path is correct, but it won't show up in the Crystal report.

thanks again.

Comment: There is nothing to be taken for granted.

As I have already written, problems can be different.
Is the path a relative path or absolute path?
Also, does the user have permissions to access that path?

Comment: Thanks again Giorgio, what I meant is that the image is not being read from a windows location or path, the image is stored directly in the Oracle DB in a BLOB column and is read by Crystal through ODBC from there. The test I did was using the DB owner user so it has complete admin rights to all Oracle tables.

Comment: Sorry, but since it's not a good practice to do it, I did not realize that you have the pictures stored in a table.
In that case I do not know how to help you, because personally I use to memorize the path into table, never the image. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the images on the Oracle database  type field for bmp instead of jpg and now they show fine.